# Getting currently selected row in a devArt dotConnect DbDataTable (possibly DataTable)

Tags: .net, ado.net, datatable, devart, dotconnect

I'm writing a control that will simplify some of the editing process in a dotConnect DbDataTable component.

Part of the editing process is being able to call BeginEdit() and EndEdit() on the current row. Many articles make it clear that the current row is not managed in the DataTable, however I'm wondering if that isn't completely accurate or whether the DbDataDable (from dotConnect) adds this layer.

I can create a DbDataTable (in the form of an OracleDataTable) on a form, and attach 1) a DataGridView and 2) a set of data bound controls such as TextBoxes and CheckBoxes (using the DataSource property on both).

This means that when the current row changes in the grid, the values in the data bound controls also change. The data bound controls aren't aware of the selection in the DataGridView, yet their values change accordingly.

I've looked at all the properties and inspected everything about the table but I cannot find anything remotely useful. The only lead I had was the DefaultView property which suggests it can include a cursor position, but nothing more is exposed about this.

The documentation for dotConnect is pretty lacking in terms of usage examples so I was not able to find much there either (nor in Google).

Does anyone have any information on whether this data can be extracted from a DbDataTable component or will my component not work without associating the DataGridView as well (which makes it a lot less flexible). Another option would be to create a BindingSource, but then I have to change the bindings on all the controls to use that binding source.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I ended up using is to use a BindingSource. This is not the best solution either, as there's definitely some buggy behavior in the coupling between the BindingSource and the DbDataTable/OracleDataTable. But after some experimenting I was able to figure out workarounds for these too.